# how to run sqlscripts in sql automatically and how to save the input in given path

Tags: sql

i have some sqlscripts to run daily at 9.00 AM. how to make my work automatically and save the output in given path.please help out
 for example, query like select emply from emply_list where salary > 50,000

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: operating System is Oracle

Comment: Do you mean Oracle Enterprise Linux?

Comment: yes,operating system-linux,database- Oracle

Comment: Which DBMS and SQL client?

Comment: Oracle and standard SQL